# Azure App Service: SNAT Port Exhaustion Issue

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, azure-service-plan

We have a app service A with 3 instances. This service is hosted in app service plan shared by other app B with 0 traffic. App Service Plan is Premium v3 P1V3.

The app service A receives around 2 million requests every day. App Service in turn makes calls to more than 50 different backend services/APIs hosted in a common/same Azure Api Management. So, base URL for different APIs is same while route path is different. Though internally, these backend services are different but APIM routes it to correct domain services using the APIM policies.

These backend services that are exposed via common/same APIM gateway are being consumed by different clients/Partners apart from our App Service.

The app Service A also makes calls to Azure Storage Account (storing each request/response in a blob for logging purpose, queuing some messages, pulling some keys from Key vault).

We are consistently seeing SNAT Exhaustion issue (Failed SNAT connections detected) in our Azure App Service A which calls these backend services. Though, not every time, it results in to socket issue. Sometimes, it ends up with socket issues. We also found that sometimes one of the domain services takes longer than expected time due to peak load (let's assume 10-20 seconds for may be 100 calls while for remaining 1000's of calls may be in milli seconds). We have no control on the backend services response. And, it is possible due to multiple reasons that one of the backend service API is responding slow.

Through some research, we found that Pre-allocated SNAT count is 128 for each instance. And, it can be increase based on demand but there is limit on the app service (combination of all instances). Though not sure of the exact number?
We think since our destination base Url is same for all 2 Million calls we are making every day. Sometimes due to increase traffic during certain period, the SNAT ports are not being released or we are reaching the limit or exhausting that.

Note: We are using typed client consumption pattern of HttpClientFactory of .net 6. And, confirmed that it handles connection pooling very well.
For TCP connections, it says no issues. But, I am just adding few graphs found from Azure portal diagnosis here.

If connection pooling is correct, Microsoft recommends VNET integration for service endpoint/private endpoint or VNET Integration with NAT Gateway. We see VNET integration without NAT Gateway is cheaper but not sure how to configure that.

Not sure if we can consider our backend services as service endpoint. Since these cannot be secured/made private as they are being consumed by other partners/clients today

Also, we have tried VNET Integration with NAT Gateway in lower environments but still see the allocation limit of SNAT ports on each instance as 128. How can we be sure that the SNAT Port count has increased to higher limit? SNAT Port shows that pre-allocated is 128 even with NAT Gateway.

Is there any other option available to fix below issue?

Also, since we are calling Azure storage account for every call (to store blobs/queue messages/key vault), would that be a cause for concern. Note that we are using same client connection to queue messages/blobs).

SNAT Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

We initiate our services something like below. Just to ensure basics are good.

Startup file

```
    services.AddHttpClient<IAService, AService>();
    services.AddHttpClient<IBService, BService>();
    services.AddHttpClient<ICService, CService>();
```

Service file:

```
    public class AService : BaseClassClient, IAService
    {
        public AService(HttpClient client) : base(client)
        {
            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(“https://test.com/xyz/”);
        }

    Other methods.
    }
```

Any suggestions to fix SNAT issue would be of great help.

Comment: I am not sure why someone clicked on Close button. If any additional info is needed, pls do ask.

Comment: I've experienced this in past but it got solved by scaling the App Service Plan, but it does not seem to be the case... I found these pages, I think it worth to check https://4lowtherabbit.github.io/blogs/2019/10/SNAT/ & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-intermittent-outbound-connection-errors

Comment: I did go through it and it was not much helpful in this case. As we have different backend services which has different response times sometimes and it varies a lot from service to service. For now, we went with VNET NAT Gateway route. thanks!